# why I cant rotate 2 points to draw in the same line

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have this code to draw some vertex and edges, and 
I have tried almost all the possibilities that were within my reach, but I believe the bug is in the method rotate or in the construtor 
but I'm not sure

```
public static int CONFIG_NODE_DIAMETER = 20; //pixels

    //construtor
    public GraphDraw(Graph<V, E> graph) {

        //count of vertex
        int N = graph.numVertex();

        double width = this.getWidth();
        double height = this.getHeight();

        Point2D center = new Point2D(width / 2, height / 2);

        double angleIncrement = 360f / N;

        //get all vertex from graph
        ArrayList<Vertex<V>> vertex = graph.getVertex();

         //draw the line and point
        boolean first = true;
        Point2D p = null;

        for (Vertex<V> v : vertex ) { {
            if (first) {
                if (width > height) {
                    p = new Point2D(center.getX(),
                            center.getY() - height / 2 + CONFIG_NODE_DIAMETER * 2);
                } else {
                    p = new Point2D(center.getX(),
                            center.getY() - width / 2 + CONFIG_NODE_DIAMETER * 2);
                }

                first = false;
            } else {
                p = rotate(p, center, angleIncrement);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

the method that makes the rotation between 2 points

```
private static Point2D rotate(Point2D point, Point2D pivot, double angle_degrees) {
        double angle = Math.toRadians(angle_degrees); 

        double sin = Math.sin(angle);
        double cos = Math.cos(angle);

        //translate to origin
        Point2D result = point.subtract(pivot);

        // rotate point
        Point2D rotatedOrigin = new Point2D(
                result.getX() * cos - result.getY() * sin,
                result.getX() * sin + result.getY() * cos);

        // translate point back
        result = rotatedOrigin.add(pivot);

        return result;
    }
```

[image]

I wanna do like the image below and I tried to rotate but it is not working

[image]

any suggestion?

[in this link, you can check all method in class GraphDraw, and I dont put because the post would be extensive](https://ideone.com/bqyoaa)

Comment: Have a look at the AffineTransform class, it will do what you need.

Comment: How do you draw the graph? Why do you stepwise rotate a single point in the loop? You do not do anything with the result anyways so what's the point?

Comment: I have the new method to `redraw` the graph and I  dont put because the post would be extensive , my doubt is just to rotate

Comment: you can check the class GraphDraw, in this link [click here](https://ideone.com/bqyoaa)